# MySQL: is it more efficient to query for duplicate row or insert(update) on duplicate?

Tags: mysql, update, insert, best-practices

Just curious on resource efficiency.  If I have a list of inserts that need to be accomplished repeatedly which may contain duplicates (there is no way around this, the API I have to work with sucks), is it better for me to query for the primary, and only insert if it doesn't exist (ie. 2 queries), or just insert anyway with update on duplicate syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a 3rd option: `INSERT ... SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (...);`

Comment: Would this be the most efficient option In terms of resources?

Comment: Not sure. It will just avoid producing some gaps in the auto_increment column (if you have one.) I think the efficiency depends on how many duplicate values you expect. I suggest you do some testing with all options. My preference would on the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` or the `NOT EXISTS` version.

Comment: How many rows per second do you expect to be inserting? If the volume is small, it may not be worth optimizing this. Just make something that works.

Comment: Right now it will be 40 duplicates every hour.  But there's no cap on that number, it it will go up over time.  I don't expect it to EVER be > 1000 records, but the API I'm forced to use is sluggish as is, and am looking to save resources where I can.

Comment: 40 rows inserted per second is rather average, starting to get interesting. 40 per hour is just nothing.

Comment: The most I could expect would be ~250/hour.  I understand that it's a pretty insignificant amount relatively.  Would I even notice performance benefits of efficiency here?

Comment: Option #4:  `INSERT IGNORE ...`.  Be sure to have a `UNIQUE` key for discovering dups.

Comment: Option #5 (but do not use it):  `REPLACE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At 250/hour, all possible techniques are plenty fast.  Anyway, I will throw my 2 cents in...

Multi-row `INSERT` of 100 rows will run 10 times as fast as 100 individual `INSERTs`.

Multi-row `INSERT` *may* lead to gaps in `AUTO_INCREMENTs`.  In general, the command will preallocate all the ids it *might* need, then 'burn' the ones id did not use.  (`REPLACE` burns lots, since it is `DELETE` + `INSERT`.)

For efficient "normalization" do something like:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO HostNorm (host_name)
    SELECT DISTINCT s.host_name
        FROM Staging AS s
        LEFT JOIN HostNorm AS n  ON n.host_name = s.host_name
        WHERE n.host_id IS NULL;
```

- A list of possibly new values is in `Staging`.
- `HostNorm` is where 'new' rows need to be put.
- Only 'new' rows are fed to `INSERT` (see `LEFT JOIN`).
- `IGNORE` is to accommodate having multiple threads (connections) doing similar inserts that could collide.  (A rare collision would lead to a burned `id`.)
- There is no cap on how many rows this can handle.
- This works best with, say, 100 rows.
- This is designed for very high speed input; it should work fine for your relatively slow ingestion rate.

More discussion in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table).

Comment: This is fantastic and something I would have never come up with on my own. Thanks!